# React app throwing errors when using 'react-pdf'

Tags: reactjs, webpack, create-react-app, react-pdf

I've been having trouble getting react-pdf to work properly in my react app that I created using 'create-react-app'. From various github comments on the react-pdf page, it seems that there's an issue setting up the workerSrc in React applications that were created with 'create-react-app'.

One work around that seemed to solve the issue (temporarily) was to copy the **pdf.worker.js** file from the **node-modules/build/pdfjs-dist/build** folder and place it in the public folder of my react app. Then in my index.js file put the following code:

```
  import  {pdfjs}  from 'react-pdf' 
window.PDFJS.workerSrc  = process.env.PUBLIC_URL + '/pdf.worker.js'
```

This worked just fine for a week, until I installed a new module into my application with npm. Now, I'm getting the same error I did in the beginning, and nothing has changed:

```
index.js:14 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'workerSrc' of undefined
```

These were the initial comments that helped me narrow down the error:
https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/1574#issuecomment-280436498

https://github.com/wojtekmaj/react-pdf/issues/291

but now that it's back I'm kind of at a loss for ideas. Has anyone else experienced this and been able to solve it? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Based on what I have seen in the docs and in forums, it appears you should be altering the global PDFJS object.

PDFJS.workerSrc, instead of window.workerSrc.

Comment: Hey Tom thanks for the response! I tried what you mentioned and still get the same error:TypeError: Cannot set property 'workerSrc' of undefined

Comment: Youre comment did make me realize I pasted the line from my code incorrectly though! What was PREVIOUSLY working was : window.PDFJS.workerSrc  = process.env.PUBLIC_URL + '/pdf.worker.js'

Answer (score 1):

I managed to get this working by loading the worker from CDN.

```
import { Document, Page, pdfjs } from 'react-pdf';

pdfjs.GlobalWorkerOptions.workerSrc=//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdf.js/${pdfjs.version}/pdf.worker.js
```